# How to exclude passes from EXR file when using the denoiser node?

Tags: compositing-nodes, denoise, .exr

Situation:

Blender: 2.81a, Cycles
1 Scene, 1 View layer

View layer passes:
Combined,
Normal,
Diffuse Color,
Emission

Using the Normal and Diffuse Color as inputs to the denoiser.
Denoiser outputs directly to Composite node.

Want to write to OpenEXR MultiLayer file:

-Compositor output and emission only.

-but not the Normal and Diffuse Color pass.

How to exclude the Normal and Diffuse Color passes from EXR file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just plug in the outputs from the Render pass or other nodes that you need directly to the inputs of a **File Output** node.

EXR multilayer can have any number of arbitrary layers (use the Add input button on the node to create them), so just create the ones you need for further compositing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks cegaton, that solved it.  One problem I had though is that in the output properties I still was writing EXR multi-layer to the same directory/filename.  That would overwrite the EXR file from the File Output node. In the above(screenshot) situation, what would you normally put in your output properties? ie, filename, type, etc because that always seems to generate some image somewhere... thx again

Comment: The output can be arbitrary. Just write the path and name you want. You can still output an EXR multilayer using the file output and a different dummy file using the composite ouptut (this last file can be some other format that you want, so that it does not conflict with EXRs and you really do not need it)

Comment: ok, gotcha. Thanks for the help!